# Особенности работы JupyterNotebook. Вопрос по работе модуля logging в Python. Дублирование вывода

Tags: python, логирование, jupyter-notebook

Приветстсвую! Изучаю модуль logging в Python. Я уже привык тестировать нечто новое в JupyterNotebook и этот раз не стал исключением. 
Вот код, который я запускаю:

```
import logging
import otherMod2

def main():
    """
    The main entry point of the application
    """

    logger = logging.getLogger("exampleApp")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create the logging file handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler("new_snake.log")

    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add handler to logger object
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    logger.info("Program started")
    result = otherMod2.add(7, 8)
    logger.info("Done!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

В otherMod2.py:

```
import logging

module_logger = logging.getLogger("example_App.otherMod2")

def add(x, y):
    """"""
    logger = logging.getLogger("example_App.otherMod2.add")
    logger.info("added %s and %s to get %s" % (x, y, x+y))
    return x+y
```

Вот что, должно печататься в файл "new_snake.log":

```
2019-08-31 12:32:52,491 - exampleApp - INFO - Program started
2019-08-31 12:32:52,491 - exampleApp.otherMod2.add - INFO - added 7 and 8 to get 15
2019-08-31 12:32:52,491 - exampleApp - INFO - Done!
```

Что интересно, при повторном запуске `main()`, происходит дублирование каждой строки. Т.е. запись в файл становится:

```
2019-08-31 12:37:26,414 - exampleApp - INFO - Program started
2019-08-31 12:37:26,414 - exampleApp - INFO - Program started
2019-08-31 12:37:26,415 - exampleApp.otherMod2.add - INFO - added 7 and 8 to get 15
2019-08-31 12:37:26,415 - exampleApp.otherMod2.add - INFO - added 7 and 8 to get 15
2019-08-31 12:37:26,415 - exampleApp - INFO - Done!
2019-08-31 12:37:26,415 - exampleApp - INFO - Done!
```

При третьем запуске пишется соответственно:

```
2019-08-31 12:38:04,835 - exampleApp - INFO - Program started
2019-08-31 12:38:04,835 - exampleApp - INFO - Program started
2019-08-31 12:38:04,835 - exampleApp - INFO - Program started
2019-08-31 12:38:04,835 - exampleApp.otherMod2.add - INFO - added 7 and 8 to get 15
2019-08-31 12:38:04,835 - exampleApp.otherMod2.add - INFO - added 7 and 8 to get 15
2019-08-31 12:38:04,835 - exampleApp.otherMod2.add - INFO - added 7 and 8 to get 15
2019-08-31 12:38:04,836 - exampleApp - INFO - Done!
2019-08-31 12:38:04,836 - exampleApp - INFO - Done!
2019-08-31 12:38:04,836 - exampleApp - INFO - Done!
```

Что самое интересное: в случае запуска `main()` в PyCharm - всё рааботает нормально. Это именно особенность работы JupyterNotebook. Я думал, что проблема в том, что я несколько раз делаю `import otherMod2` по сути, код внутри otherMod2 выполняется каждый раз. Однако при обычном запуске `main()` вывод продолжает увеличиваться везде на один. Что это за особенность такая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, как написано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#logging.getLogger):

> All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger
>   instance. This means that logger instances never need to be passed
>   between different parts of an application.

Можно попробовать чистить (`logger.handlers.clear()`) так:

```
import logging
import otherMod2

def main():
    """
    The main entry point of the application
    """

    logger = logging.getLogger("exampleApp")
    if (logger.hasHandlers()):
        logger.handlers.clear()

    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create the logging file handler
    fh = logging.FileHandler("new_snake.log")

   formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
   fh.setFormatter(formatter)

   # add handler to logger object
   logger.addHandler(fh)

   logger.info("Program started")
   result = otherMod2.add(7, 8)
   logger.info("Done!")

if __name__ == "__main__":

#logger.addHandler(handler)
    main()
```